# Python C extension function that accepts optional integer

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I want to implement a following Python function in a C extension module:

```
def value(x: Optional[int] = None) -> Optional[int]:
    if x is None:
        # act like a getter
        return APIGetValue()  # retrieve the value from an external library
    # act like a setter
    APISetValue(x)  # pass the value to an external library
    return None
```

Here is what I got so far:

```
static PyObject* MyLib_PyValue(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs) {
    static char *kwlist[] = { "x", NULL };
    int x;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, "|i:value", kwlist, &x)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (x == NULL) {
        return PyLong_FromLong(APIGetValue());
    }
    APISetValue(x);
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Calling the function with args works, but when calling `value()` as a getter, I get `1` instead of `NULL`. How should I proceed? I'm not very familiar with Python's C API yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can't have a NULL int. NULL is a thing for pointers. Due to the way C type conversion works and how the `NULL` macro is defined, `x == NULL` with an int `x` usually does one of two things: it behaves as `x == 0`, or it produces a compile-time error.

Second, quoting the [Python C API argument parsing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html),

> The C variables corresponding to optional arguments should be initialized to their default value — when an optional argument is not specified, PyArg_ParseTuple() does not touch the contents of the corresponding C variable(s).

This is also true of `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords`. Your `x` is uninitialized, and `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords` doesn't write a value for it, so accessing the value of `x` in the `x == NULL` comparison is undefined behavior.

You need to initialize `x`, and you need to use a type that actually allows you to detect missing values. That probably means declaring `x` as `PyObject *x = NULL;` and passing `"|O:value"` to `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords`, then handling the conversion to C long inside your function instead of relying on `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords` to do it.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the fast answer! Doing my first steps into C and Python C API, so bear with the question stupidity.

Answer (score 1):

This is the end result, in case someone needs a working snippet:

```
static PyObject* MyLib_PyValue(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs) {
    static char *kwlist[] = { "x", NULL };
    PyObject *pyX = NULL;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwargs, "|O:value", kwlist, &pyX)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (pyX == NULL) { // getter
        return PyLong_FromLong(APIGetValue());
    }
    // setter
    int x = (int)PyLong_AsLong(pyX);
    if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (x < 0) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "x must be positive");
        return NULL;
    }
    APISetValue(x);
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```